# Angularjs application listening to rest requests from my server

Tags: angularjs, observable, webhooks, server-side

I have a server that from time to time (1 in 1 minute) sends a post request. Through a Webhook.

I can visualize my requests through webhook.site

I would like to build an AngularJS application that listens to requests (post) and renders the body on the screen in real time, in the same way as this site: [(https://webhook.site/)](https://webhook.site)

I don't know how to do it, if you have a simple example that I can use using postman to trigger the request:
Ex:

> POST "update site" url: siteangula/update/text-page

```
{
 text: "hello"
}
```

every time I fire the request, the page would update text

Server: Kotlin Spring-boot
Client: Angula JS